# ¿como puedo incluir el framework spring en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, spring

Hola amigos soy nuevo en el desarrollo de programacion java y me pidieron que utilizara el framework spring para el desarrollo web java pero entro a su web y no veo ni un botón de descarga de los archivos del framework o el .jrar y ni nada por el estilo como lo podría integrar al NetBeans 8.1

Disculpen por mi ignorancia agradecería sus comentarios positivos?

Answer (score 3):

Te recomendaría que empezaras usando spring boot initializr:
https://start.spring.io/

Esto te genera un proyecto base en función de las dependecias que le indiques para empezar a programar directamente. Verás que en el fichero pom.xml ya importa la librerías de spring.

En el siguiente enlace te explica muy básicamente como funciona:
http://www.arquitecturajava.com/que-es-spring-boot/

Se usa eclipse, pero con netbeans puedes importar el proyecto que te genera spring boot initializr fácilmente como proyecto maven.

Necesitarás tener instalado maven.

Answer (score 2):

Al crear en NetBeans una aplicación web, una vez rellenados todos los campos referentes al nombre de la misma, el servidor que vas a utilizar, etc, al final te da la opción de integrar en tu aplicación distintos frameworks, entre ellos Spring, pero creo que es necesario tener instalada la versión para J2EE. Si no es el caso, desde la sección de pluggins puedes actualizar el entorno.

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo me hice un [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/61470/jar-searcher) para buscar los jars, ya que pocos sabíamos usar maven en mi escuela o como descargar el jar desde un repositorio maven.

Una vez que tengas el jar que necesitas abres el item llamado libraries de tu proyecto

[image: item libraries de netbeans]

Le das click derecho y verás tres opciones

[image: menú contextual el libraries]

Las que te sirven son agregar librería o agregar Jar.

En mi caso tengo una distribución llamada Coolbeans y no tiene la librería de spring por defecto, revisa, igual y tu ya la tienes y solo tendrías que seleccionar.

[image: dialogo de librerías]

Si como en mi caso no te aparece deberás buscar y descargar un jar de spring y seleccionar la opción de JAR/Folder; te abrirá una ventana de selección

[image: selección de un jar]

Te deberá de aparecer en la carpeta de librerías y eso indicará que ya estará en tu classpath al compilar.

Este método es para los proyectos "normales" de netbeans que puedes notar por el icono de una tacita roja y que internamente usa una tecnología llamada [ant](/questions/tagged/ant).

Si agarras otro tipo de proyecto como Maven o Gradle basta con definir la dependencia de maven central o le repositorio maven de tu preferencia y solita se descarga y se agrega al classpath.